# Add / Replace content in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have buttons in which when I click on I add a div to another div which is working fine as below.

```
$("div.swatch-opt").append($(divPrice).text());
```

The issue I am facing is if the I click another button with same class, the content which I am getting is not getting replaced but being added up. So basically the requirement is to replace the content if already appended. Below is the code which I am using to make the div.

```
$.each(priceArr, function(price,val) {
      spanPrice  += "<span>"+val+"</span>";                                    
});

divPrice = "<div class='divPrice'>";   
divPrice += spanPrice;             
divPrice += '</div>';
```

So the `divPrice` div is the one which I want to add in the end of the swatch-opt div. The click event triggers various outcomes for `priceArr`, so each time the `divPrice` has different outcome.

At one time it can be - `<div class='divPrice'><span>75</span><span>75</span><span>80</span></div>`

Or can be - `<div class='divPrice'><span>75</span><span>75</span><span>80</span></div>`

So if I apply the above code, the outcome is adding the div instead of replacing it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make much sense at all. It would help to see a more complete sample of your HTML and JS code.

Comment: You're creating HTML, and after that extracting `text()` from your HTML, doesn't make any sense. Also `append` is to only for appending HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated my question please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an html text (divPrice) then you use the `$(divPrice).text()` function when appending this last to parent div , and this is usless because it'll only append text contained in divPrice ,

So to achieve what you want use `$("div.swatch-opt").append(divPrice);` and to  remove last added when clicking again youo have to add only `$("div.swatch-opt").find(".divPrice").remove();`

See below sample snippet :

```js
var priceArr = [],
  spanPrice = "",
  divPrice = "";
$(".btn").on("click", function(e) {
  priceArr = [];
  spanPrice = "";
  divPrice = "";
  this.innerHTML == "S" ? priceArr = [75, 75, 80] : (this.innerHTML == "M" ? priceArr = [70, 70, 80] : priceArr = [65, 70, 85]);

  $.each(priceArr, function(price, val) {
    spanPrice += "<span>" + val + "</span>";
  });
  divPrice = "<div class='divPrice'>";
  divPrice += spanPrice;
  divPrice += '</div>';
  
  $("div.swatch-opt").find(".divPrice").remove();
  $("div.swatch-opt").append(divPrice)
})
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn">S</div>
<div class="btn">M</div>
<div class="btn">L</div>
<div class="swatch-opt">

</div>
```

Comment: You're Welcome @Tester :)

Answer (score 3):

To replace the content use `.html` instead of append. `append` will only insert the element not replace it.

```
 if($("div.swatch-opt").find("div.divPrice").length>0)
{
    $("div.swatch-opt").find("div.divPrice").html($(divPrice).text());
}
else
{
   $("div.swatch-opt").append($(divPrice).text());
}
```

Comment: I do not want to replace the html of swatch-opt class. I want to add the divPrice in the end of the swatch-opt class.

Comment: updated my answer. First check if price div is already added, if yes then replace otherwise append